# “Use The New Keyword To Create An Object Instance”

Tags: vb.net

I am not sure what is wrong with this part of the program. Every time I run it there is an error message saying:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

On the line `cc.RawDataString.IndexOf("B")`.

Code:

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim cc As New CreditCard

    Dim posB, posC1, posC2, posBlackSlash As Integer

    posB = cc.RawDataString.IndexOf("B")
    posC1 = cc.RawDataString.IndexOf("^")
    posC2 = cc.RawDataString.IndexOf("^", posC1 + 1)
    posBlackSlash = cc.RawDataString.IndexOf("/")

    cc.RawDataString = txtRawData.Text
    lblCCNumber.Text = cc.Number

    lblCCNumber.Text = cc.RawDataString.Substring(posB + 1, posC1 - posB - 1)
    lblLname.Text = cc.RawDataString.Substring(posC1 + 1, posBlackSlash - (posC1 + 1))
    lblFName.Text = cc.RawDataString.Substring(posBlackSlash + 1, posC2 - (posBlackSlash + 1))
    lblYear.Text = cc.RawDataString.Substring(posC2 + 1, 2)
    lblMonth.Text = cc.RawDataString.Substring(posC2 + 3, 2)

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems either `cc` or `cc.RawDataString` is null.

Comment: This doesn't look much like VBA. Did you mean VB.NET?

Comment: At the top of the window says "Microsoft Visual Studio"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you reference `cc.RawDataString` before you set it to something.

Comment: I hovered the arrow on posB=cc.RawDataString.IndexOf("B")  and says "cc.RawDataString Nothing". Probably that is the problem right?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.  You set `cc.RawDataString` a few lines later.

Comment: My first class of VB. I thank you very much FIRST for your valuable help, SECOND that fixed my problem. Thank you, thank you.